# django GenericForeignKey group by

Tags: django, group-by

I have a model X with a GenericForeignKey. model Y and model Z instance attached in model X GenericForeignKey.

```
y1 = Y.objects.create(name=y1)
y2 = Y.objects.create(name=y2)
z1 = Z.objects.create(name=z1)
x1 = X.objects.create(content_object=y1)
x2 = X.objects.create(content_object=y1)
x3 = X.objects.create(content_object=z1)
```

I want to a query that queryset result it x1 and x3(means group by content_object instance)
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to group by content_type.
You can use something like this.
`X.objects.values('content_type').annotate(dcount=Count('content_type'))`

Comment: Is this works right for you? It shows **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation**

Comment: Yes. You should add GenericRelation as an attribute in your Models Y and Z.

[Refer django documentation - GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation)

Comment: But there is still a question, using objects.values('content_type') can't return the model X instance, only **content_type**. I want to return the model X instance and call it's method like `x.show_all()`